# What app needs to be whitelisted in OSX's Security&Privacy Accessibility list, so that my bash script can send keystrokes?

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, osascript

I am writing a simple (haha) bash script that will send keystrokes to an app. It uses the osacript command line to do this, like so:

```
osascript <<EOSCRIPT
    activate application "Mini vMac"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "a"
EOSCRIPT
```

When this script is run, it does bring the app to the front, but then I get the following error:

```
77:90: execution error: System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed to send keystrokes. (1002)
```

I have tried whitelisting /usr/bin/osascript but other search results suggest that it doesn't want this. The bash script itself is unselectable (which doesn't necessarily mean that it doesn't want it, just that I can't check).

How do I force it to let me run this? 10.14.6 Mojave if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have **Mini vMac**; however, on **macOS Mojave 10.14.6**, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* should work to send a *keystroke*, assuming a **Mini vMac** window is open, and **Terminal** is given permission in: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

```applescript
osascript -e 'activate app **Mini vMac**' -e 'delay 0.25' -e 'tell app "System Events" to keystroke "a"'
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for this. I saw Terminal in there, but it had become unchecked, and I didn't notice until you posted this answer. Thanks much.